# AngularJs $rootScope

Tags: angularjs, rootscope

I have two separate module that both end up at the same view via $rootScope.

I'm trying to put a condition in that will allow me to force a user back up a set path. What I need is to be able to add a unique identifier to one of the $rootScopes.

What I have is:

```
$rootScope.go(url)
```

and I would like something like

```
$rootScope.go(url + 'unique id')
```

with out messing up my pathing.

Any way to achieve this?

Comment: Your question is unclear for me .... can you try to express it in a different way ?

Comment: There is only one $rootScope.

Comment: Hey sorry, I posted on the MAC vs. PC question you deleted and suggested that you try programmers instead.  I did that because of this answer: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/51670/why-do-programmers-use-or-recommend-mac-os-x, but I got a nasty msg back saying that was a bad recommendation.  My bad, I didn't realize it.

Comment: No worries at all, I appreciate you taking the time to comment regardless. Looks like I'm going to have to just Google my answer myself, didn't realise it was a sensitive question...